# Email Address Authentication (dots and capitalization)

Tags: php, mysql, email, authentication

As you can know there are a lot of characters that can be used in a e-mail address.
People nowadays split some keywords in their e-mail address to improve readability, eg:

```
name.surname@gmail.com
x-com.shop.support@stuff.net
```

However, the dot character `.` when using Gmail (as well as capitalization) only improves readability, it is not taken in account as a part of e-mail address. Thus, we can say that:

`name.surname@gmail.com` is the same as `namesurname@gmail.com`

`x-com.shop.support@stuff.net` is the same as  `x-comshopsupport@stuff.net`

---

**The problem**

Most of websites use a database-driven authentication. Assume that I registered a email (without dots) `namesurname@gmail.com` then, such a MySQL query will not work as the strings differ:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "name.surname@gmail.com" ;`

---

**The question**

Is there any workaround to solve this kind of problem? In fact different e-mail servers use different rules. So do users have to always remember, on which website they have used dots or capital letters, even that e-mail address is still the same?

---

***UPDATE***

Just imagine some service, where you could make tonns of accounts using the same e-mail.
Original email is `namesurname@gmail.com`, aliases:

```
name.surname@gmail.com
n.amesur.name@gmail.com
nam.esurname@gmail.com
```

And still you will be getting e-mail confirmations on the same address. Sounds strange, huh?

Comment: It depends entirely on the receiving server whether `foo.bar` is treated as the same address as `foobar`, there's no such general specification.

Comment: With capital letters there is no problem - you can insert lowercased form and check against it. As for dots, it is Gmail feature, but other mail providers may treat those as two separate emails.

Comment: Alright, that info is pretty useful

Comment: "capitalization [..] is not taken in account" This is a common misconception: *domain names* (at right of @) *are not* case sensitive. But *[local parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part)* (at left of @) *are* case sensitive. Except for the special case `postmaster`. Most MTA are configured to ignore case sensitivity of the "local part". But this is absolutely not required. In fact [RFC5321](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) clearly state that "The local-part of a mailbox MUST BE treated as case sensitive."

Comment: @SylvainLeroux awesome information it could be possible answer

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Posted as [an answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18171414/2363712).

Comment: Also [special for Gmail addresses](http://gmailblog.blogspot.de/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html): everything after the first `+` in the local part is omitted and can be used for labeling or whatever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *really really* want to solve you issue the way you propose, you will have to store your email address as some kind of canonical form. Say all lower-cases and by removing "dots" or any other special character you want to ignore.

You could "automatize" the thing by using a trigger (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81689/1):

```
create table email(addr char(80), canon char(80) UNIQUE);
CREATE TRIGGER ins_email BEFORE INSERT ON email
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.canon = REPLACE(LOWER(NEW.addr), ".","");

INSERT IGNORE INTO email(addr) VALUES ("Sylvain.Leroux@example.com"),
   ("sylvainleroux@example.com"),
   ("SYLVAINLEROUX@ex.ample.com");
```

This will only insert *one* row in the table based on the canonized form.
Please look carefully at the last example. The domain is "ex.ample.com" which is canonized by my simple trigger as "examplecom". Which is probably *not* desirable. This is just to pinpoint that correct canonization might probably be a little bit more complex than `REPLACE(LOWER( ...` . In addition you will probably need to create a duplicate `ON UPDATE` of this trigger. But...

---

**... I won't go further in that direction as:**

> "capitalization [..] is not taken in account"

This is a *common misconception*: domain names (at right of @) *are not* case sensitive. But [*local parts*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part) (at left of @) *are* case sensitive. Except for the special case `postmaster`.

Most MTA are configured to ignore case sensitivity of the "local part". But this is absolutely not required. In fact [RFC5321 section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.4) clearly state that "The local-part of a mailbox MUST BE treated as case sensitive."

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I'm not familiar with *gmail* and I was most surprised by reading that anything after `+` is ignored !?! Ironically, the e-mail address of the author of RFC5321 is *john+smtp@jck.com* :D

Comment: ... well after all, every mail delivery system is free deliver/forward mail as it wish. The *real* problem is for us at application-level. Do we have to strictly comply with the RFC, or do we have to take into account each and every subtleties of various mail provider, as popular as there are? Especially here, since email address is sometime viewed as some kind of "unique user ID".